# Chartsjs.org and Ember Js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to render this [linechart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) using Ember js on my screen
The line chart requires an array of labels for each of the data points. This is show on the X axis.

My controller

```
lineChartData = {
    labels : ["09:00am","09:15am","09:30am","09:45am","10:00am","10:15am","10:30am"],
    datasets : [
      {fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",pointStrokeColor : "#fff",data : [0.025,0.050,0.075,0.025,0.050,0.1,0.0]}
    ]
}
```

Handlebar

`{{view Portal.LineView datasetsBinding="lineChartData"}}`

View

```
Portal.LineView = Ember.View.extend
  classNames: ['canvas']

  didInsertElement: ->
    @renderChart()

  renderChart: ->
    view = @
    canvas = view.$()
    if (canvas)
      Chart(canvas.getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData)
```

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getContext'
```

Comment: any jsbin of jsfiddle link??

Answer (score 1):

In order for chart to work the element needs to be a canvas.   I think you tried to do that, but really you're creating a div with the class `canvas`

```
<div class='canvas'></div>
```

You'll want to use `tagName`

```
Portal.LineView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'canvas'

  didInsertElement: ->
    @renderChart()

  renderChart: ->
    view = @
    canvas = view.$()
    if (canvas)
      Chart(canvas.getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData)
```

Additionally I'm going to assume `lineChartData` is a global variable somewhere.